# Реализовать, чтобы при наведении мышки отгинался угол

Tags: css

Подскажите как реализовать чтобы при наведении мышки отгинался угол.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С эти разобрался! Взял две картинки без угла и с углом и готово.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы это имели ввиду. Это плагин для wordpress.
[Загнутый угол веб страницы — плагин Page Peel](http://bloggood.ru/wordpress/zagnutyj-ugol-veb-stranicy-plagin-page-peel.html/)

Comment: Да я про это знаю. но мне необходим не плагин. http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=109 типа этого

Comment: ну и что вам не нарвится в туториале, кроме того что он глючный ?

Comment: берете плагин и разбираете его...

Comment: вы бы решение вопроса поподробней расписали бы, а то ответ на вопрос неполный